# Screenshot and Share in Flame Flutter

Tags: flutter, screenshot, share, flame

I'm making a simple game in Flame and I need an in-game feature where users can screenshot their high score and then share it directly to popular social media such as Instagram, Twitter, etc.

I've tried a couple of packages for Flutter but it's either I didn't understand them well or they weren't the right solutions for my particular needs.

Comment: For taking a screenshot in Flutter you have https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot, and for sharing the same to social media you have https://pub.dev/packages/social_share

Comment: @gLanceD I think you'll have to specify what packages you've tried and why they weren't the right solution for you, for us to be able to help you.

Comment: @inkredusk Sorry but code formatting is not for brand names. I have rejected your edit.